# How can I add a query string to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, button

I've got a fairly basic question for everyone concerning a query string.

I need to add a query string to a button and am not sure how to go about it. I'm not very strong with either JavaScript nor jQuery, so and ALL advice will be tested and greatly appreciated.

This is the button code ...

```
<button>Lorem Ipsum</button>
```

I need to add this query string (btw the string is URL encoded) to that button ...

```
http://responsetoday.com/jointventure-ecomm/purl54pki3r.aspx?rid=TST1232544
```

Comment: Are you wanting the user to click the button and go to that url?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. Is there any specific attribute on the button that should have the URL as value? Should it be inserted via JavaScript?

Comment: Okay so when the end user clicks that link they will then be sent to an advisor where they can they chat.

Comment: @SimonSteinberger yes I think JavaScript would be the "best" way to go.

Answer (score 2):

No javascript needed, you can use a hidden field in the form:

```
<form action="http://responsetoday.com/jointventure-ecomm/purl54pki3r.aspx" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="rid" value="TST1232544">
    <button>Lorem Ipsum</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need javascript for this. For goodness sake people. Just style an `<a>` tag to look like a button. Then you have the advantage of semantic markup (meaning an  tag is expected to have a link to another page).

```
<a href="http://responsetoday.com/jointventure-ecomm/purl54pki3r.aspx?rid=TST1232544">
     Lorem Ipsum
</a>
```

And then styling it with css to look like a button. For example:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  border: #ccc 1px solid ;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #eee;
  box-shadow: inset 2px -2px 3px #ddd;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font: sans-serif .9em;
  }
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: #ddd;
  box-shadow: inset 3px -3px 4px #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<a href="example.com">Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

Comment: Hey JakeParis,Thanks for your response. I agree 100% with your solution and would not have had a problem were that my option. Unfortunately, I had to follow the client's request.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must keep the `button` tag, you could add an onclick event like so:

```
<button onclick="location.href='http://responsetoday.com/jointventure-ecomm/purl54pki3r.aspx?rid=TST1232544'">Lorem Ipsum</button>
```

However, a (IMHO) cleaner approach would be to wrap a submit button in a form with an action of the target URL:

```
<form action="http://responsetoday.com/jointventure-ecomm/purl54pki3r.aspx?rid=TST1232544">
  <input type="submit" value="Lorem Ipsum">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi jayrobin, wondering if I could bug you a bit more. The client is not happy with the solution. They would like to see a GET instead of having the post "?" URL being hard coded. I do not understand this request at all. How can I proceed?

Comment: @Frankie [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26680564/361762) results in a GET request. It was also the first one posted--is there some reason it doesn't work for you? I should also mention that the first option posted in jayrobin's answer will also be a GET.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows how to target a `button` with a specific ID and make it preform the specific GET action you specified.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lorem").on("click", function() {
      window.location = "http://responsetoday.com/jointventure-ecomm/purl54pki3r.aspx?rid=TST1232544";
    });
  });
</script>
<button id="lorem">Lorem Ipsum</button>
```

If you're not really comfortable with javascript/jQuery and want something simple that "just works", the following is probably the shortest, simplest solution. I made this a runnable, so you can see it in action if you click "Run code snippet."

```html
<button onclick="window.location='http://icanrespond.ca/kff-ecomm/purl3r.aspx?rid=TST1234'">Lorem Ipsum</button>
```

Comment: Dave I did not mean to ignore your answer. I was just trying ti find what I perceived as the easiest. And that is not to say or suggest the any of these answers are simple. On the contrary, due to my very weak JavaScript and/or jQuery skills all these answers proved to be a bit too technical for me ...

Comment: ... I was not sure how to insert your code. When I tried the other solution the client was not happy because I had "hard-coded" everything after the '?'. They do not want that. The numbers after the '?' will be dynamically input by the GET. So I admit fully and completely I am a very green around the ears JavaScript developer. Any further advice or hand holding would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it more clear and I added a simple alternative. What is unclear though is how you are supposed to get the dynamically generated URL parameter (the part after the `?`). Does the parameter get stored in another javascript variable? Is it generated by an AJAX request? If you can let me know where that value comes from then we should be able to create a fully-functioning example.

Comment: Hi dave, thank you for the update. I tried your solution, and yes I am very uncomfortable with JavaScript so I went with the simplest solution. The CTA works, but it still goes to a blank page. I was just chatting with a friend of mine about this and he feels my client has not supplied me enough information. Here is the URL of the calculator ... http://client-staging.info/KFF/kff/index-eng.html?http%3A%2F%2Ficanrespond.ca%2Fkff-ecomm%2Fpurl3r.aspx%3Frid%3DTST1234 ... I hope this helps a bit more.

Comment: If it's bringing back an empty page that's not on you, it is the client's page. This code will work just as if the user typed that link into the browser or clicked on that link.

Comment: Thank you dave. I did end up using your code, and have sent off the project to my client to review. I'm sure they will not be happy, but after speaking with you and several other posters here, and a friend of mine, this client has not given me enough information. When they get back to me, and if things did not work out, I will have to ask for more details. Thanks again!!!

Comment: You're welcome. The way to show thanks here would be to upvote the answer and potentially accept it.

Comment: dave, I just tried to upvote your answer but it would not allow me to do so. Apparently I do not have enough cred points to do so, sorry. Will try again soon.